# React Helmet works in development but not production

Tags: reactjs, gatsby, react-helmet

I'm currently using `react-helmet` in my GatsbyJS project. I'm trying to add titles for each page, within the head. It's working in development, but not when I deploy. I've tried deploying to both Github Pages and Netlify with no success.

[Development](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Hb0ed.png)

[Deployment](https://i.stack.imgur.com/61tBk.png)

```js
import React from 'react';
import Layout from '../components/Layout';
import P from '../components/designSystem/P';
import Link from '../components/designSystem/Link';
import H1 from '../components/designSystem/H1';
import Helmet from 'react-helmet';
import { siteInfo } from '../data';

const page = 'About';

export default () => (
  <Layout>
    <Helmet>
      <title>{siteInfo.title + ' | ' + page}</title>
    </Helmet>
    <H1>About Me</H1>
    <P>
      Hi! I'm Adway. I'm currently a sophomore at Saint John's High School in
      Shrewsbury, Massachusetts. 
</P>
  </Layout>
);
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you include `react-helmet` (`gatsby-plugin-react-helmet`) in your `gatsby-config.js` file.

```
module.exports = {
  plugins: [
    "gatsby-plugin-react-helmet"
    ]
};
```